# Use Google Analytics to count user visits from an image

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics

i have a problem with PHP and Google Analytics. Basically what i want to do is to count a visit when the user access this image from my email `<img src='path/to/image' />` from his email client in in **Google Analytics**.

```
// If is a view then just show an image
if($mysqlAction == "VIEW")
{
    // Create a blank image and add some text
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    readfile('image.jpg');
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-35932495-2']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

My problem is that after

```
    // Create a blank image and add some text
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    readfile('image.jpg');
```

it is useless to put any code, because the output of `script.php` will be like accessing an `image.jpg` , but i really need to count views in google analytics.

What i want :

1. How can i solve this?
2. Don't give me an alternative like TrackReports from Sendblaster ... or any similar solution.

My ideas are :

1. My idea was something with double buffer like first show the analitycs code and then `ob_flush()` the image
2. Fetch with `CURL` another page or something ...
3. Use Analitics for PHP ...

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the solution in this article: http://techpad.co.uk/content.php?sid=186

Author implements PHP class to access google analytics service from server side instead of client side JS.

I hope it will help.

Comment: i want to track users that opened an email, that might be a library for retrieve data from an Google Analitycs account

Answer (score 0):

You could tag your hyperlinks with campaign tracking (see http://cutroni.com/blog/2008/11/04/email-tracking-with-google-analytics/), but aside from that, I don't know how you could do this. Support for JS in email clients is flaky at the best of times, and of course, you cannot include JS inside an image. My suggestion would just be to tag your hyperlinks in your email, and at least that way you'll know inside Analytics how many visitors came from your email campaign.

If you're wanting to track how many of these emails are read etc, then they can be used in your current method (php blank image). However, you won't then be able to then send this data to Analytics, you'd have to develop your own way of using the data.

That being said, no one is forced to download these images nowadays, so the metrics you'll get back are estimates at best.

Comment: I already finished that, i mean when you access count.php it gathers data and put in mysql, but believe me i really need to implement Analitycs as well, this is i must do

Comment: If that is the case, then your best bet would be to take a look at Mikhail Payson's suggestion. Although I can't say I've used that method before - that's the first time I've heard that you can send data to Analytics server side.